# Regex pattern to match string on the basis of "Starts with" and "Number of occurrences"

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find out only URLs those starts with `http://www.example.com/blog/` and total number of character `/` is exactly `5`.

So it won't matches URL like

```
http://www.example.com/blog/category/cat-1/
http://www.example.com/blog/category/cat-2/
http://www.example.com/blog/tags/a-b-c/
```

It should only match URLs like

```
http://www.example.com/blog/a-blog-title/
http://www.example.com/blog/another-blog-title/
http://www.example.com/blog/just-one-more-blog-title/
```

I have tried a lot on [regxr](http://www.regexr.com/) but could not create one.

I will implement it in C# (if it makes any different).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: something like `/(.+)\/\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/([^/]*)/`

Answer (score 2):

You want something like:

```
bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(str, "^http://www.example.com/blog/[^/]*/[^/]*$");
```

(starts with your url, has 0-n characters, followed by a /, followed by 0-n characters, end of the string)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^http://www.example.com/blog/[^/]*/[^/]*/$");
```

Comment: Replace the $ with another [^/]*$ if there is additionional info afterwards like parameters

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of task i'd use the `Uri` class instead, for example (tested with a text file):

```
Uri uri = null;
var uris = File.ReadLines(filePath)
    .Where(l => Uri.TryCreate(l.Trim(), UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
    .Select(l => uri);

var validUris = uris
    .Where(u => u.Host == "www.example.com"
             && u.Segments.Length == 3
             && u.Segments[1] == "blog/");
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the different and 100% valid answer. I m curious to know, would it also matches urls without `www` or with `https`. If not, how can we modify the solution to achieve this as well in a most possible efficient way because number of URLs I have is very huge..?

Comment: @AnimalsAreNotOursToEat: it also parses Uri's without www but the `Where` above filters them out because of the `Host` which contains `www`. Note that i've edited my answer because the `http` is not part of the `Host`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
^http://(?=www.example.com/blog/)([^/]*/){3}$
```

Would match any url that starts with `www.example.com/blog/` (after the `http://` bit) and has a total of 5, two in the `http://` and 3 in whatever comes after.

Not very well versed in C# so I'm not sure how to best apply the expression however.